# JavaScript critical error at line 5, column 9 in (unknown source location)

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, visual-studio-2012, internet-explorer-11

I am using visual studio 2012

I have this simple html page, **not asp.net page**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Test Float</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="slideBar"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I run it on google chrome. it works good.

when I debug it on internet explorer. I got this error:

[image]

#### Edit

For those who think that the sytle sheet is the problem. here is my style sheet

```
html, body {
margin:0px;
height:100%;
}
.header {
    width:100%;
    height:20%;
    background-color:red;
}
.footer {
    width:100%;
    height:20%;
    background-color:green;
}
.slideBar {
    width:20%;
    height:60%;
    float:right;
    background-color:blue;
}
.content {
    width:80%;
    height:60%;
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

It is working very good on google chrome and mozilla. the code is very very simple. just that IE11 is not

#### Edit2

After I added my html page link to the compatibility mode. I got this exception:

[image]

Comment: Just guessing here, but should it be `class="sideBar"` instead of `class="slideBar"`? You need to check your style sheet.

Comment: This works loads for me on MSIEv10. Of course, I don't have your stlye sheet, so nothing displays. Another thought: if this is on an HTTP server or your local machine is Mac or LUnix, maybe `href="Styles/style.css"` should be `href="styles/style.css" `

Comment: I wonder how Internet Explorer can report a script error, since there are no scripts in your page. Is that your whole markup?

Comment: @jedison i edited my question and added the css file. the code is very simple and working on all other broswers

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi yes as always IE is super bad browser. IE should be in the gennis book as the badest browser ever ever

Comment: Works fine. I have 4 sections: top in red, middle left in yellow, middle right in blue, and bottom in green. On MSIEv10. Ah, oops. You are on MSIEv11. Just a guess, but you might need to turn Compatibility Mode ON. [link]http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/use-compatibility-view

Comment: @jedison it is working good on other browsers. just when I debug the code on the IE11 i got that problem. really really mad of IE. any suggestion for fix?

Comment: @jedison what is this compatibility thing please? where should I active it?

Comment: @jedison I can't believe that. I am using visual studio, which is a microsoft product. I am trying to debug the code on IE, which is a microsoft product. then I need to make compatitoblity? i completely believe that you may be true because microsoft products are always "shi...."

Comment: Check the link to the Microsoft explanation. You set that your page/website should have Compatibility View. Tap or click the Tools button Tools, and then tap or click Compatibility View settings.
Under Add this website, enter the URL of the site you want to add to the list, and then tap or click Add.

Comment: If possible, avoid MS development tools and browsers :P Eclipse isn't great for HTML, but it works. And Chrome is miles better than MSIE, IMHO. Please let me know if that works then I will add an official answer and you can check it off so that others know "why" (Microsoft) and "how to fix it".

Comment: @jedison I am forced to use their browser because this is the rule of where i am working. also, this is my first try with vs. I used to working with simple notepad on linux. believe me the notepad in linux is better than the whole 9GB vs 2012

Comment: Completely understand the work requirements; sounds like a bank.

Comment: @jedison do you mean to add this `http://localhost:8726/index.html` in the compatibility box?

Comment: @user, something is definitely amiss here, it really looks like your browser is parsing scripts that are not in your page. Can you reproduce the problem when running IE in safe mode (`iexplore -extoff`)?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I am running the IE from my vs2012. so the vs2012 runs the IE. how can I tell the vs2012 to run that Ie in a safe mode?

Comment: @user, you will have to add that entry to your Browse With list and set it as default. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scicoria/archive/2013/03/26/visual-studio-ie-debug-with-no-add-ons.aspx.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi yes that works. I can't believe that. thanks man. write an answer please

Comment: I had a similar issue recently and it turned out to be an error in my JS. From your screenshot it looks that in your case the root is not located in an external JS file, but in some inline <script> tag (I'm assuming that form the "unknown source location". Are you sure that you don't have any extra html code other than the fragment you pasted? If so, please put the rest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your browser is apparently running an add-on that injects scripts into loaded pages, and these scripts cause problems with IE11 (and 10).

You can configure Visual Studio to run IE in safe mode by adding an `iexplore -extoff` entry to the Browse With list and setting it as default, as explained [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scicoria/archive/2013/03/26/visual-studio-ie-debug-with-no-add-ons.aspx).

That said, I would recommend investigating which add-on is responsible for this situation, as it may have other adverse effects to your web usage (and to your privacy), and you may want to remove it if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

You are on MSIEv11. Just a guess, but you might need to turn Compatibility Mode ON. [link]http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/use-compatibility-view#ie=ie-11
You set that your page/website should have Compatibility View. Tap or click the Tools button Tools, and then tap or click Compatibility View settings. Under Add this website, enter the URL of the site you want to add to the list, and then tap or click Add.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the reasons why you think compatibility view would solve the problem?

Comment: Because this works just fine on MSIEv10, but not with MSIEv11.

Comment: I added my html page link to that compatitility mode. and I got an exception. I edited my question to add the new exception.

Comment: Oh wait, these exceptions are appearing in MS-VS not in MSIE. What happens when you try it outside of MS-VS directly in MSIE?

Comment: @jedison check the comments on the question. Frederic Hamidi helped me

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I see that Frederic found the VS matter.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to share my experience, 
in my case, I was using lambda expressions to find some elements in a list like

```
myList.find(ro => ro.field1 == field1);
```

And internet explorer doesn't support lambda expressions.

I created some functions in order to find items.

It works.