# jQuery Critical Error in jquery.js v3.3.1

Tags: jquery

I just started getting this jQuery Critical error in the jquery.js file v3.3.1, attempts to load the file in the windows script host generated the same error.  The error is:

```
JavaScript critical error at line 3888, column 14 in http://localhost:4101/javascripts/jquery.js\n\nSCRIPT1010: Expected identifier
```

I had to use an older version of jquery to be able to use jQuery.  This JUST started happening today, any one know whats going on with this?

**UPDATE**

It seems that an IE addon is causing the problem.  When I use the "browse with" option with the -extoff command, jQuery loads fine.

So, in IE I open Tools->Manage Addons, in the Add On dialog I look at "All Addons" and disable them one at a time and run my code each time, each time jQuery fails to load because of the error noted above. After ALL the addons are disabled, jQuery STILL refuses to load, yet but when I "browse with" -extoff the code runs fine. What am I missing?

Comment: refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23155927/javascript-critical-error-at-line-5-column-9-in-unknown-source-location?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: "This JUST started happening today" something must have changed then. What environments? is it in a specific browser?, or all browsers? I wouldn't expect jQuery to work in anything but a browser.

Comment: I get the same error with all add-ons disabled ... :(

Comment: @Anfath Hifans, ok ... after a few tweaks it would seem that an add-on is the problem, now to find out which one  ...

Comment: @phuzi, apparently I got a drive-by add-on, this wasn't happening earlier this morning and suddenly it started happening.  I wasn't working with my javascript code when this happened, I was changing the size of a button.  When I disable all add-ons, no problem.  Now I have to figure out which one.  :(

Comment: In IE I open Tools->Manage Addons, in the Add On dialog I look at "A  Addons" and disable them one at a time and run my code, each time jQuery fails to load because of the error noted above.  After ALL the addons are diable, jQuery STILL refuses to load, but when I browse with -extoff the code runs fine.  What am I missing?